# $C[0,1]$ is NOT a Banach Space w.r.t $\|\cdot\|_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to find a cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$ that converges under $\|\cdot\|_2$ to a limit which isn't continuous.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of "converges under $\|\cdot\|_2$ to a limit which isn't continuous," you probably want "does not converge under $\|\cdot\|_2$ to a limit which is continuous."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$f_n(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0 & \text{if } x \leq 1/2,\\
1 & \text{if } x \geq 1/2+1/n,\\
n(x-1/2) & \text{if } 1/2\leq x\leq 1/2+1/n.
\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: Does this sequence work for showing C[0,1] is not Banach for any $p<\infty$? I can see it works for $p=1$ & $p=2$.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Yes it does actually, I have just checked it.

Comment: A quick question: Why $\|\cdot\|_1 \leq \|\cdot\|_2 \leq \|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ ?

Comment: I'm not completely ure. I think for simple functions you can use the corresponding reult for finite dimensioal spaces and then take limits.

Comment: @rk101: $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|\cdot 1dt \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(t)|^2dt}\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1 1dt}=\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\int_0^1|f(t)|^2dt}\leq\sqrt{\int_0^1\|f\|_\infty^2 dt}=\|f\|_\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Another one.  Think of a discontinuous (bounded measurable) function.  Say: $f(x) = 0$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $f(x) = 1$ on $(1/2,1]$.  Write down its Fourier series.  The partial sums are continuous.  They converge in $L_2$ norm (to $f$) but do not converge to any element of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Note that $f$ should be not only discontinuous, but not a.e. equal to any continuous function.  E.g. $f(1/2) = 1$, $f(x) = 0$ otherwise is discontinuous, but its Fourier series converges uniformly to the continuous function 0.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the function that is $0$ on the interval $\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ and then is $y=n(x-1)+1$ on the remainder of the interval.  As $n$ increases the "spike" gets sharper.  The limit function is not continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: However, the limit function in the $L^2$ norm is $0$, which is in $C[0,1]$. *These aren't the pointwise limits you're looking for...*