# Completeness of normed spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

As earlier, I have received an answer from this site that Bolzano Weierstrass' theorem is true for finite dimensional normed spaces, but not for infinite dimensional spaces. This, in particular => all finite dim. normed spaces are complete(in the sense that every Cauchy sequence converges(w.r.t. norm)). However, **is it true that every normed vector space is complete?**

Comment: We wouldn't need the words "Banach space" if this were true :)

Comment: There a lot of examples. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114070/how-to-prove-that-ck-omega-is-not-complete/114131#114131

Comment: Ignore my previous (non-)answer. Since I don't want to bamboozle you with function spaces I'm now trying to think of a vector space that is incomplete and is not a function space.

Comment: This might be an easier example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143857/c0-1-is-not-a-banach-space-w-r-t-cdot-2/143861#143861

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I don't insist...

Answer (score 3):

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous, real-valued functions on $[0,1]$. Then $$\|f\|=\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx$$ defines a norm on this space. The sequence of functions defined by $$f_n(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0 & \text{if } x \leq 1/2,\\
1 & \text{if } x \geq 1/2+1/n,\\
n(x-1/2) & \text{if } 1/2\leq x\leq 1/2+1/n.
\end{array} \right.$$

is Cauchy, but does not converge. I have recycled the sequence from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143861/21674).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here we go: take the one dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$ with the usual norm $|q|$. Then you can find a Cauchy sequence that converges to an irrational, hence the space is not complete.

Or: sequences that are non-zero only in finitely many places (over $\mathbb R$) and you can take the norm to be the $\ell^1$ norm, i.e. $\|x\| := \sum_i |x_i|$.

Comment: This is not a vector space.

Comment: Dear Matt, can you just point me out what your "+" operation means in your vector space R or in your subspace (0,1)? Because in case it is the normal addition operation, then how can (0,1) be a subspace at all? Because 0.9 is in (0,1), but 0.9 + 0.9 = 1.8 > 1!!

Comment: @SomabhaMukherjee Sorry, didn't see the "vector" in your question. Let me correct my answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. I think I managed to fix my answer.