# Identify closed linear subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Is $C[a,b]$ a closed linear subspace of $L^p(a,b)$,$1\le p\le \infty$? And why? The linear subspace part is quite straightforward, but I am not sure about the closedness part.

Comment: There's a theorem about density of continuous functions in $L^p$ spaces. What does that say about your problem?

Comment: $C_c[a,b]$ should be dense in $L^p(a,b)$, which says any function in $L^p$ is a limit of a sequence of functions from $C_c[a,b]$. But the problem is whether $C[a,b]$ is closed given the $L^p$ norm.

Comment: Right. But what is the definition of "closed", and how does it related to what you just stated?

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is closed for $p=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I almost omitted this case. The theorem indeed says only the denseness for $1\le p<\infty$. For $p=\infty$ $C[a,b]$ should be complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and $S\subseteq X$.  If $S\neq X$ and $S$ is dense in $X$, then $S$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=0$ and $b=1$. Define a sequence of functions by $$f_n(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0 & \text{if } x \leq 1/2,\\
1 & \text{if } x \geq 1/2+1/n,\\
n(x-1/2) & \text{if } 1/2\leq x\leq 1/2+1/n.
\end{array} \right.$$

This is a sequence of continuous functions that converges to a limit that is not equal almost everywhere to a continuous function.

Recycled from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143861/21674).